# How to create a Mondrian schema (xx.mondrian.xml) for MySQL data base

Tags: mysql, mondrian, saiku

I am going to customise [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com/) analysis tool for my local MySQL data base. For that I have to change the their existing data source as following manner,

```
type=OLAP
name=steelwheels
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampledata; \>Catalog=../webapps/saiku/steelwheels/steelwheels.mondrian.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
username=dbuser
password=password
```

According to above code, can any one please tell me how I generate Mondrian schema file called **steelwheels.mondrian.xml** with MySQL data base **sampledata**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and open PSW or Pentaho Schema Workbench which can be found as part of the mondrian project on sourceforge.

This is going away with Mondrian4, but thats ages away at the moment.

Comment: Many thanks for the valuable answer, I will try that and let you know. Have a nice time!

Comment: 2015 and we still have the same problen about PSW.

See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17469/software-to-edit-mondrian-schemas

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pentaho BI server then its really easy to create `*.mondrian.xml` file for your datasource using *Pentaho User Console* it will be easy to create and edit datasource and just use `*.mondrian.xml` file created under `/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/admin/resources/metadata/`.

I use that in my regular practice. It will be effective even if you dont use pentaho for your whole application but just use *pentaho user console* for this purpose.

Comment: I beleive that the new version has this information stored in JackRabbit. 

Try to access it through the REST API. See for example: http://127.0.0.1:8080/pentaho/api/repo/files/etc:metadata/children

Answer (score 0):

At this moment my best solution is to use the data source wizard to create a new analysis, export it manually and edit it by hand in your favorite xml editor. (Example Notepad++ with XMLTools plugin).

Sadly it works better than using the old Pentaho Schema Workbench. You may try to create a DTD to validate the structure of XML against the schema. See the [official documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php).

Maybe the Enterprise version has better tools to edit it.